# Iterate through the array of Dictionary and separate the name for status true

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to iterate through this array and separate out the names that have status true.

```
var array = [["name":"joe", "status":false ],["name":"will", "status":false],["name":"smith" , "status":false]]
```

Comment: What should your output look like? An array with the name "joe" in it? or and array with `["name":"joe", "status":false ]`?

Comment: Have you tried anything before asking here?

Comment: array of name only @ Allen R

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
var array = [["name":"joe", "status":true ],["name":"will", "status":true],["name":"smith" , "status":false]]

let filteredDictionary = array.filter( { $0["status"] as? Bool ?? false } )

var names = [String]()

for dictionary in filteredDictionary {
    if let nameFound = dictionary["name"] as? String {
        names.append(nameFound)
    }
}
```

I recommend that you use a `struct` to store the values instead of a dictionary. Something like this.

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var status: Bool
}
```

If you have it like this in a `Person` array, it becomes less complicated as dictionary value optional handling can be avoided.

```
var personArray = [Person(name: "joe", status: true), Person(name: "will", status: false)
let names = personArray.filter( {$0.status} ).map( {$0.name} )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `filter` is you want to keep both the status and name, otherwise use `compactMap` is you just want to keep the name.

```
let statuses = [["name":"joe", "status":true ],["name":"will", "status":false],["name":"smith" , "status":false]]
let trueStatuses = statuses.filter({$0["status"] as? Bool == true}) // [["name": "joe", "status": true]]
let namesWithTrueStatus = statuses.compactMap{$0["status"] as? Bool == true ? $0["name"] as? String : nil} //["joe"]
```

Comment: why not simply `let namesWithTrueStatus = trueStatuses.compactMap{ $0["name"] as? String }`

Comment: can i use any alternative method using for loops like this 
for i in array {

for (name,status) in i {

}

}

Comment: @LeoDabus that would require a consecutive `filter` and `compactMap` operation, so even if the code seems a bit simpler, it has inferior performance compared to a single `compactMap`

Comment: @farieas yes, you can, but why would you? `compactMap` is much more concise and clean